# ¿Error de sintaxis en la instrucción INSERT INTO?

Tags: vb.net, basic

Estoy haciendo un sistema en Visual Basic para manipular una base de datos, y tengo todo bien -según yo-, el caso es que al momento de ejecutar el "INSERT INTO", me da error de sintaxis. Les adjuntaré la instrucción para ver si encuentran el error, al igual que unas capturas donde nos manda un msgbox con la instrucción, y del error.

```
insertarsql = "
INSERT INTO DISTRIBUCION (
    PLANTEL, 
    UBICACION, 
    NIVEL, 
    ENTIDADFEDERATIVA, 
    CLAVEDELCENTRODETRABAJO, 
    PERESC, 
    NOMBRECOMPLETO, 
    RFC, 
    GRADODEESTUDIOS, 
    TITULADO1, 
    PASANTE1, 
    EGRESADODE1, 
    ESPECIALIDAD1, 
    GRADOMAXIMODEESTUDIOS, 
    TITULADO2, 
    PASANTE2, 
    EGRESADODE2, 
    ESPECIALIDAD2, 
    DEPTOOACADEMIA, 
    CATEGORIA, 
    NUMERODECONTROL, 
    FECHADEINGRESOSEP, 
    FECHADEINGRESODGETI, 
    NODEHORASNOMBRAMIENTO, 
    PLAZAS, 
    CONDICIONESDENOMBRAMIENTO, 
    TURNODETRABAJO, 
    H_LUNES, 
    H_MARTES, 
    H_MIERCOLES, 
    H_JUEVES, 
    H_VIERNES, 
    H_SABADO, 
    H_TOTAL, 
    CA_CLAVE, 
    CA_ASIGNATURA, 
    CA_GRUPO, 
    CA_SALON, 
    CA_LUNES, 
    CA_MARTES, 
    CA_MIERCOLES, 
    CA_JUEVES, 
    CA_VIERNES, 
    CA_TOTAL, 
    CA_TOTALHORAS, 
    AC_TIPOACT, 
    AC_ACTIVIDAD, 
    AC_DETALLE, 
    AC_GRUPO, 
    AC_LUNES, 
    AC_MARTES, 
    AC_MIERCOLES, 
    AC_JUEVES, 
    AC_VIERNES, 
    AC_TOTALHORAS, 
    AC_SUBTOTALSESIONCLASE, 
    AC_TOTALSESIONCLASE, 
    GR_TOTALHORAS, 
    FECHADELLENADO) "



insertarsql = insertarsql + "VALUES (" 
        & txt_plantel.Text & ", 
    '" & txt_ubicacion.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_nivel.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_entidadfederativa.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_clavecentrotrabajo.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_peresc.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_nombrecompleto.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_rfc.Text & "', 
    '" & "', 
    '" & txt_gradoestudios.Text & "', 
    " & titulado & ", 
    " & pasante & ", 
    '" & txt_egresado1.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_especialidad.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_gradomaximo.Text & "', 
    " & titulado2 & ", 
    " & pasante2 & ", 
    '" & txt_egresado2.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_especialidad2.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_deptoacademia.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_categoria.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_numerocontrol.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_fechaingresosep.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_fechaingresodgeti.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_nodenombramiento.Text & "', 
    '" & plazas & "', 
    '" & condiciones & "', 
    '" & turno & "', 
    '" & txt_hlunes.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_hmartes.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_hmiercoles.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_hjueves.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_hviernes.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_hsabado.Text & "', 
    '" & htotal.Text & "', 
    '" & clave & "', 
    '" & asignatura & "', 
    '" & grupo & "', 
    '" & salon & "', 
    '" & hlunes & "', 
    '" & hmartes & "', 
    '" & hmiercoles & "', 
    '" & hjueves & "', 
    '" & hviernes & "', 
    '" & hsabado & "', 
    '" & hhsc & "', 
    '" & totalht & "', 
    '" & tipoact & "', 
    '" & detalle & "', 
    '" & act & "', 
    '" & grupo2 & "', 
    '" & hlunes2 & "', 
    '" & hmartes2 & "', 
    '" & hmiercoles2 & "', 
    '" & hjueves2 & "', 
    '" & hviernes2 & "', 
    '" & hhsc2 & "', 
    '" & subtotalhc & "', 
    '" & totalhc & "', 
    '" & txt_ACtotalhoras.Text & "', 
    '" & txt_ACfechallenado.Text & "')"
```

Bien, ahora las capturas:
[image: Es el insert en un msgbox]
[image: Es el error que me da]

Comment: ponlo como texto, la letra es tan pequeña que es ilegible

Comment: la forma mas facil de solucionar esas cosas, es copiar el insert de salida y probarlo directamente en la base de datos. Decir que esta todo bien, sin haber probado eso, no alcanza.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor,nunca,**nunca** generes tus queries de sql concatenando las cadenas con los campos. En vez de eso utiliza **siempre** consultas parametrizadas que hacen que tu aplicación no esté expuesta a la [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada le estas diciendo al `INSERT INTO` que le mandaras `59` campos:

```
PLANTEL
UBICACION
NIVEL
ENTIDADFEDERATIVA
CLAVEDELCENTRODETRABAJO
PERESC
NOMBRECOMPLETO
RFC
GRADODEESTUDIOS
TITULADO1
PASANTE1
EGRESADODE1
ESPECIALIDAD1
GRADOMAXIMODEESTUDIOS
TITULADO2
PASANTE2
EGRESADODE2
ESPECIALIDAD2
DEPTOOACADEMIA
CATEGORIA
NUMERODECONTROL
FECHADEINGRESOSEP
FECHADEINGRESODGETI
NODEHORASNOMBRAMIENTO
PLAZAS
CONDICIONESDENOMBRAMIENTO
TURNODETRABAJO
H_LUNES
H_MARTES
H_MIERCOLES
H_JUEVES
H_VIERNES
H_SABADO
H_TOTAL
CA_CLAVE
CA_ASIGNATURA
CA_GRUPO
CA_SALON
CA_LUNES
CA_MARTES
CA_MIERCOLES
CA_JUEVES
CA_VIERNES
CA_TOTAL
CA_TOTALHORAS
AC_TIPOACT
AC_ACTIVIDAD
AC_DETALLE
AC_GRUPO
AC_LUNES
AC_MARTES
AC_MIERCOLES
AC_JUEVES
AC_VIERNES
AC_TOTALHORAS
AC_SUBTOTALSESIONCLASE
AC_TOTALSESIONCLASE
GR_TOTALHORAS
FECHADELLENADO
```

Y en `VALUES` estas indicando `60` campos:

```
txt_plantel.Text 
txt_ubicacion.Text 
txt_nivel.Text 
txt_entidadfederativa.Text 
txt_clavecentrotrabajo.Text 
txt_peresc.Text 
txt_nombrecompleto.Text 
txt_rfc.Text 
txt_gradoestudios.Text 
titulado 
pasante 
txt_egresado1.Text 
txt_especialidad.Text 
txt_gradomaximo.Text 
titulado2 
pasante2 
txt_egresado2.Text 
txt_especialidad2.Text 
txt_deptoacademia.Text 
txt_categoria.Text 
txt_numerocontrol.Text 
txt_fechaingresosep.Text 
txt_fechaingresodgeti.Text 
txt_nodenombramiento.Text 
plazas 
condiciones 
turno 
txt_hlunes.Text 
txt_hmartes.Text 
txt_hmiercoles.Text 
txt_hjueves.Text 
txt_hviernes.Text 
txt_hsabado.Text 
htotal.Text 
clave 
asignatura 
grupo 
salon 
hlunes 
hmartes 
hmiercoles 
hjueves 
hviernes 
hsabado 
hhsc 
totalht 
tipoact 
detalle 
act 
grupo2 
hlunes2 
hmartes2 
hmiercoles2 
hjueves2 
hviernes2 
hhsc2 
subtotalhc 
totalhc 
txt_ACtotalhoras.Text 
txt_ACfechallenado.Text
```

Y otra cosa, algunos encomillados están mal, te anexo algunos que vi en tu captura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En `plantel` no tiene la comilla simple `'` para abrir y antes de `Gradoestudios` hay comillas `"` de mas.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudo demasiado, vi que tenía varios errores, aunque el encomillado inicial no es necesario, al menos en visual basic no lo es... Para evitar mirar parte por parte el código y no perder tanto tiempo decidí dividir el insert en varias partes, en varios formularios, aunque es un método de solución muy malo lo dejaré así...

Comment: Aunque tu respuesta es correcta, ten en cuenta que nunca,**nunca** hay que generar los queries de sql concatenando las cadenas con los campos. En vez de eso se debe usar **siempre** consultas parametrizadas que hacen que tu aplicación no esté expuesta a la [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL)

Answer (score 0):

bueno este ejemplo esta con una bd en mysql la instrucción para insertar seria la siguiente:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient 'importamos la libreria

 Public Class Form1  'creamos la cadena de conexion en el public
     Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("data source=localhost;user id=root; password='contraseña'; database=mibd")
    Dim cmd As MysqlCommand
```

esta instrucción va en el botón solo debes seguir la secuencia del `insert` teniendo cuidado con las comas y ampersand (&). (por eso el error de sintaxis)

```
            conn.Open()
            cmd = New MysqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into mitabla (campo1, campo2, campo3)values('" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox9.Text & " ','" & TextBox7.Text "')"

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
```